# Does "std::cin >> value" return a Zero if input is EOF?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
int main(){ 
int sum = 0, value = 0;
while (std::cin >> value)
sum += value; 
std::cout << "sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

What is the return value of **>>** operator, against which while loop is evaluated ? The program terminates on EOF input (Ctrl+Z for windows). Does that mean 0 is stored to cin in case of an EOF ? Does it have anything to do with ASCII value of EOF ?

Comment: It's `std::istream&`, but this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Hm or not this one, but in general it has numerous answers.

Comment: `stringstream` or `cin` does not matter, answer holds for all `std::istream`s.

Comment: May be a stupid question. How could the return value terminate the while loop ? Is the return value zero if input is EOF ?

Answer (score 1):

It [returns](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) a reference to `basic_ifstream`:

```
basic_istream& operator>>
```

In the context of `if`, it converts to `true` unless `std::ios_base::failbit` or `std::ios_base::badbit` is set in its state.

Comment: How could the return value terminate the while loop ? Is the return value zero if input is EOF ?

Comment: @Paul259, if the state of `cin` will be set to `failbit` of `badbit` (for example, if `cin >> some_integer_variable` reads something that is not a number), it will convert to `false` and the loop will end.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/), the return type is `istream&`.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a non-`const` reference to `std::cin`.